# Converted mp4 h264 baseline format loads long time

Tags: ffmpeg

I have converted my video to mp4 x264 baseline format and it works fine with all pc/mobile phones , the problem is it takes long time to load the video while googling came to know that ffmpeg converts and sets the index file at the eof the video so it loads to the end to read and then plays the video, So any advices would be appreciatable to cut short the loading time.
Note:tryied out QT index swapper2 but dint give much difference , please advice .

this is the cmd i used to convert -

**ffmpeg -i … -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -level 1 …**

Thanks for your time .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several options to relocate the moov atom so the video can begin playback before it is completely downloaded by the client.

### `-movflags faststart`

The easiest is the option `-movflags faststart` when re-encoding:

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -movflags faststart output.mp4
```

If you already encoded your `.mp4` file, but simply want to move the atom:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -codec copy -movflags faststart output.mp4
```

You may need to get a more recent ffmpeg version to use this option. See the [FFmpeg download](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for links to ffmpeg builds for Linux, OS X, and Windows, or you can follow a step-by-step [guide to compile ffmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide).

### `qt-faststart`

Alternatively you can use the `qt-faststart` tool that comes with the ffmpeg source:

```
cd ~/ffmpeg/tools
make qt-faststart
./qt-faststart input.mp4 output.mp4
```

### `MP4Box`

Or you could use `MP4Box` (usually provided by the `gpac` package depending on your distro):

```
MP4Box -add input.mp4 output.mp4
```

---

#### Also See

- [FFmpeg and x264 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/x264EncodingGuide)
- [FFmpeg and AAC Audio Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AACEncodingGuide)

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the timely response, will try the same , really time saver .

Comment: HI , Still it takes time to load , please advice ...thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, i just tried with another small 19 seconds  video which played in a minute in chrome rather takes time in safari , any clue.. thank you.